# Push notifications on ios app using flash professional cc and adobe air 13 on windows

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am trying to enable push notifications on my ios app that is built with flash professional cc and adobe air 13 on windows. (Have also tried with air 3.6 & 3.8)

I should mention that a have built and running several ios app using flash professional and air without any problem. It is just when I try to add the push function it fails.

It started out with building a very simple app with more or less no code, just to try if I have succeeded to generate correct certificate and provisioning profile and added correct information in the application descriptor file.

My problem is that the app ”freezes” or hang when I install it on my iPhone using ITunes. I never get an error message.

I am pretty sure I have created correct certificate and provisioning file. I have read a numerous of tutorials and previously succeeded to generate correct certificates for apps without push enables. Anyway this is have I have done it:

1)  Create a new app ID with push enabled and registered an explicit app id. (com.domain.appname)

2)  Created a CSR file on my friends MAC

3)  Created a development certificate for my app

4)  Created a provisioning file using my already existing development certificate.

5)  Export the development certificate as .p12 to my windows computer.

6)  Using Open SSL to convert the certificates to windows. (Works fine with my other certificates, so should work fine with push enables as well?)

After repeating the steps a number of times I tried to see if the error could be in the application descriptor file. I looked at different tutorials and found different suggestions on what to add. I tried them all, but it didn’t work. The code I think is right is the following

1)  Make sure the the  com.domain.appname matches the app ID generated on the apple portal

2)   Add the following lines under the  tag:

```
<Entitlements>
  <![CDATA[ 
    <key>aps-environment</key> 
    <string>development</string> 
  ]]>
</Entitlements>
```

3)  Make sure that you use development certificate and use     development in the XML file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is freezing when trying to install it's because there's an issue with your certificates / provisioning profile.

I would either

A) Use your friend's Mac to set up all of your certificates & provisioning profile or,
 B) Generate everything from scratch on your PC using OpenSSL (follow Adobe's guide here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS144092a96ffef7cc-371badff126abc17b1f-8000.html).